# I want to split an array and splice it based on some pattern inside the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Hello I couldn't figure out how to do this,

Let's say I have an array like this

```
main = [ "1","2","A","4","5","B","6","7","A","8","9","B","10"];
```

I want to get a new array with result

```
main2 = ["A","4","5","B","A","8","9","B"]
```

and finally break them apart like the following;

```
main3 = ["A","4","5","B"]     
main4 = ["A","8","9","B"]
```

As you can see I am taking out the array items from A-B that happened twice.

Comment: can you explain how the passage from main to main2 happened , I thought you were removing duplicates but that's not the case , so can you please explain what do you want to get from main to main 2 and what basse you want to divide them afterward to get main3 and main4

Comment: What is the logic to deriving `main2` from `main`? Just remove the first, second elements, keep next 4 elements and then remove 2 elements, keep 4 elements and remvoe the last element?

Comment: @nermineslimane I want to get the pattern- here strings- returned as I have clearly stated. From main I am removing 1,2,6,7 and 10 and returning main2 .

Comment: @jsN00b No that would be hard coded...I want to remove based on the A-B pattern not the first or second element

Comment: When you say "A-B pattern" are you referring to removing every other element?

Comment: @user1599011 I mean A and B will be a repeating items in the array. I want to store whatever is between A and B and store it in an array, if that is clear.

Comment: Find the index of A and find the index of B that comes next after that A and splice your array based on those indices. Repeat as often as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the old-school approach.

```js
const main = ["1", "2", "A", "4", "5", "B", "6", "7", "A", "8", "9", "B", "10"];
const start = "A";
const end = "B";
let result = [];
let isCollecting = false;

main.forEach(item => {
  if (item === start) isCollecting = true;

  if (isCollecting) result.push(item);

  if (item === end) {
    console.log(result);
    result = [];
    isCollecting = false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could reduce the array into arrays, starting with a certain value and ending with another.

```js
const
    start = 'A',
    end = 'B',
    data = ["1", "2", "A", "4", "5", "B", "6", "7", "A", "8", "9", "B", "10"],
    result = data.reduce((r, v) => {
        if (v === start) { r.push([v]); return r; }
        const last = r[r.length - 1];
        if (last?.length && last[last.length - 1] !== end) last.push(v);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Another approach

```js
const
    start = 'A',
    end = 'B',
    data = ["1", "2", "A", "4", "5", "B", "6", "7", "A", "8", "9", "B", "10"],
    result = [];

let i = data.indexOf(start);

while (i !== -1) {
    let j = data.indexOf(end, i + 1);
    result.push(data.slice(i, ++j));
    i = data.indexOf(start, j);
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```